# Setting custom margins using geometry package results in incorrect indent style of itemize

Tags: margins, indentation, geometry

I'm currently writing a report and the professor asked me and also other students who do that to use a specific margin. My documents uses the `article` document class and also

```
\usepackage[left=25.4mm, right=25.4mm, top=25.4mm, bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
```

for setting the proper margins of the content on the page. The problem is that whenever I used `itemize` (I presume the same happens to `enumerate` and `description`) the items get a completely off indentation - very far to the left and even going outside the viewable part of the page:

[image]

I'm using the `geometry` package for the first time and have no idea what is happening. I have never had such issues before. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: `itemize` uses `leftmargini` as value for the first level of the list. Your `geometry` settings interfere with this value. And actually, the labels are too wide, in my opinion

Comment: Why don't you use the `description` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not `geometry`'s fault. As Bernard says, this is a job for `description`.

Comment: In other words, itemize reserves a space (\bibindent) which is only big enough for a bullet or a small number, and fills this space from the right using \llap.  Anything larger gets pushed into the margin.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments. I thought that `description` obeys the same rules as `itemize` but I guess I was wrong. I changed it and it looks like a charm. @Bernard if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I would gladly accept it as such. Also I don't think I understand what @Christian Hupfer meant by "the labels are too wide". Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: I think I can explain: in a ‘normal’ itemize or enumerate the label box is aligned from the right, so if it is too wide, it can go into the left margin. A description environment, on the other hand, is aligned from the left.

Comment: Aaah, now I get it. :D I guess yeah, "Printing availability" is way too long for a label. :X Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for really long labels, enumitem has long labels, and the label boxes, for  enumerate or itemize environments are aligned from the right, at a fixed distance from the left margin of the page. To circumvent this problem, you can:

- either use a description environment, with label boxes aligned from the left,
- or load the `enumitem` package and use as an optional argument `align=left`, or `wide` (left-aligned label + left margin of the environment=left margin of the page).

Note that, if you have very long labels, enumitem allows for multined labels in description environment.